# change cpanel log file location

Tags: server, performance, cpanel, logging, whm

Is there a way in some configuration file to specify a new folder to put all the cpanel log files in, or is there a way to specify new log file names for each log?

I ask this because I want to store the files in ram since some of them are written to at least every minute from hackers failed attempts to break the system.

I tried symlinking to files in memory but that costs me in server performance. I'm trying to make my websites faster by logging in ram.

Comment: Which log files are you referring to? More than just the access and error logs (`CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` Apache directives respectively)?

Comment: The standard log files found in /usr/local/cpanel/logs folder